# Need help finding text inside of class inside of Id

Tags: javascript

so title is kinda messy, can't really explain in so little words.

So, as you can see in the print, I have an ID with the name "b2-Carousel", couple childs below I have a class called "active" and a couple childs below that class I have a text that starts with "Id:" I need to get those last digits after the "Id:" with JS.

I need to acess the text that starts with "Id:" that's somewhere inside a class "active, that's somewhere inside an id "b2-Carousel".

Hopefully that explains it, is this possible to do in JS?

[Code Print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mr4VE.png)

Comment: Post code, not images of code

Answer (score 3):

- Select the element by ID...
- Select the next element by class
- Select the next element by attribute

So the selector would look like:

```
var text = document.querySelector('#b2-Carousel .active [data-expression]').textContent;
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
/* get all divs inside #b2-Carousel -> .active */
let divs = document.body.querySelector('#b2-Carousel .active div')
/* convert nodeList to array */
divs = [...divs]
/* filter array for only divs that include the text 'Id' */
let ids = divs.filter((div) => div.textContent.includes('Id'))
/* in ids array you'll find all divs that include the text id
```